# How to only return unique values without COUNT or GROUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My database class has me stumped on this problem. If anyone could help me that would be great

I have a table that has 2 columns. Column 1 is soda types (Coke, Pepsi, Dr. Pepper, etc) and Column 2 is names of people. People can drink multiple types of soda.

Some entries might be

1. Coke Jeremy
2. Diet Coke Sam
3. Dr. Pepper Jeremy

I have to write a query that returns people that only drink one kind of soda. So Jeremy would not be returned, but Sam would. THe problem is I can't use COUNT or GROUP (or any aggregate functions)! How would I do this without those?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at all into `EXISTS` (and more importantly `NOT EXISTS`)?

Comment: Why you can't use aggregate functions? They are available for some reason, and I think it's the simplest approach.

Comment: @Barranka It's an assignment and that's part of the assignment

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
select a.soda, a.person 
  from table a
 where not exists(select 1 
                   from table b 
                  where b.person = a.person 
                    and b.soda <> a.soda)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, if sub-queries are ok:

```
select distinct * from sodas as s1 where s1.name not in (select s2.name from sodas as s2 where s2.name=s1.name and s2.soda <> s1.soda)
```